# Share location in WhatsApp showing map on continental scale

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, geolocation

When I want to share my location with someone on WhatsApp, it gives me a list of places, two of them close to my home, and the third is Panama (the country! And I live in Brazil). I thought it was some cache issue on my phone, perhaps I've searched Panama in Google Maps recently, I wasn't sure. So I looked at the same option in both my father and my mother phones, and their WhatsApp have the same problem: Panama is also the third on the list. However, their app didn't zoom out to show Panama, as mine do. This is a nuisance, because I have to increase the zoom every time I want to share a different location browsing the map.

So, why is WhatsApp (or Google Maps?) so worried about Panama? And why will my phone zoom out to include this country in the visible map, while my parents' phones will not? Can I remove Panama from this list? (Or any other distant place, the other day it was a place I've never been to, in another Brazilian state.)

[WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23112542/?category=5245251) says: "Choose Location to send your location or a nearby place." I don't know why is it considering that Panama is "nearby" Brazil, but of course something is wrong here. Anyone have similar issues? Google only tells me about the "awesome new feature of live location", it doesn't matter if I included keywords such as "error", "issue", "strange behavior". Even the + that used to work behind a word to make it required doesn't work anymore...